# lock-free stack, replace Acquire in is_empty() with Relaxed

Tags: rust, stack, lock-free

There is a lock-free stack [here](https://github.com/crossbeam-rs/crossbeam/blob/master/crossbeam-epoch/examples/treiber_stack.rs) based on epoch based reclamation from Crossbeam.

I add some notes to help me understand this implementation.

```
#[derive(Debug)] 
pub struct TreiberStack<T> { 
    head: Atomic<Node<T>>, 
} 


#[derive(Debug)] 
struct Node<T> { 
    data: ManuallyDrop<T>, 
    next: Atomic<Node<T>>, 
} 


impl<T> TreiberStack<T> { 
    pub fn new() -> TreiberStack<T> { 
        TreiberStack { 
            head: Atomic::null(), 
        } 
    } 


    pub fn push(&self, t: T) { 
        let mut n = Owned::new(Node { 
            data: ManuallyDrop::new(t), 
            next: Atomic::null(), 
        }); 


        let guard = epoch::pin(); 


        loop { 
            let head = self.head.load(Relaxed, &guard);   // (1) ’Relaxed’ only provides atomicity
            n.next.store(head, Relaxed);  // (2) ‘Relaxed’ only provides atomicity
        // (2) uses ‘head’ from (1). so (2) and (1)’s partial order won’t be rotated by CPU and compiler

            // it seems that compare_and_set behaves just like compare_and_swap.
            // It guarantees that all
            // memory operations before the RELEASE operation will appear to happen
            // before the RELEASE operation with respect to the other components of the system.
       //  So (1) and (2) always execute before (3)
            match self.head.compare_and_set(head, n, Release, &guard) {   // (3)
                Ok(_) => break, 
                Err(e) => n = e.new, 
            } 
        } 
    } 



    pub fn pop(&self) -> Option<T> { 
        let guard = epoch::pin();  
        loop { 

            // It guarantees that all memory
            // operations after the ACQUIRE operation will appear to happen after the
            // ACQUIRE operation with respect to the other components of the system.
            let head = self.head.load(Acquire, &guard);    // (4)


            match unsafe { head.as_ref() } { 
                Some(h) => { 
                    let next = h.next.load(Relaxed, &guard); // (5) ’Relaxed’ only provides atomicity


                    if self 
                        .head 
                        .compare_and_set(head, next, Release, &guard)   
                        .is_ok() // (6)
                    // This RELEASE matches the ACQUIRE in (4). Code between them won’t be reordered by CPU and compiler
                    { 
                        unsafe { 
                            guard.defer_destroy(head);  
                            return Some(ManuallyDrop::into_inner(ptr::read(&(*h).data))); 
                        } 
                    } 
                } 
                None => return None, 
            } 
        } 
    } 


    // Returns `true` if the stack is empty. 
    pub fn is_empty(&self) -> bool { 
        let guard = epoch::pin(); 
        self.head.load(Acquire, &guard).is_null()   // (7)
    } 
} 


impl<T> Drop for TreiberStack<T> { 
    fn drop(&mut self) { 
        while self.pop().is_some() {} 
    } 
}
```

My question is: Can I replace (7)'s `Acquire` with 'Relaxed'? It seems that Atomicity at (7) is sufficient enough to make it work. `Acquire` is usually pairs with `Release` to provide `Visibility`:

> after
>        an ACQUIRE on a given variable, all memory accesses preceding any prior
>        RELEASE on that same variable are guaranteed to be visible.  In other
>        words, within a given variable's critical section, all accesses of all
>        previous critical sections for that variable are guaranteed to have
>        completed.

What role does `Visibility` play in this code? It looks like the ordering of code and atomicity is the only guarantee I need to make this code work. Without `Visibility` the other thread will see the outcome of `store` eventually. So the code still works correctly.

I learned lock-free majorly from Linux Kernel's Doc [here](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/memory-barriers.txt)

Answer (score 0):

> My question is: Can I replace (7)'s Acquire with 'Relaxed'? It seems that Atomicity at (7) is sufficient enough to make it work.

Suppose we used `Relaxed` instead of `Acquire` as proposed. The `Release` at (3) does not guarantee that `is_empty()` would see the memory access of the thread calling `push()`. It might become particularly important for a consumer thread that used the Treiber stack like

```rust
if !my_stack.is_empty() {
  let elem = my_stack.pop().unwrap();
  // Do things with elem...
} else {
  // Do something expensive...
}
```

> [...] the other thread will see the outcome of store eventually.

You're correct. However, I'd like to minimize the amount of time I do expensive operations. In the above snippet, I would expect `is_empty()` and `pop()` to consistently indicate that my stack is in the same state. We lose that guarantee if the methods use different atomic orderings, and we might end up doing more expensive work just because `is_empty()` didn't synchronize yet.

Additionally, Treiber's lock-free stack is usable in multi-consumers, multi-producer contexts. Suppose one thread is calling `push()`, a second thread is calling `pop()`, and a third thread observes the stack's state via `is_empty()`. Without an `Acquire` memory order, the third thread has no guarantee of observing the same state that the pushing or popping threads observe.